# Pureadmin not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: pure-ftpd

I installed pure-ftpd and pureadmin on my computer which is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd pureadmin
```

Everything seemed to install fine.

However, when ever I try to open PureAdmin, I get the password entry field, and after entering my password nothing happens?

Any ideas on what to check?

Answer (score -1):

Coming in late for an answer, but I once had the same issue and it appeared that pureadmin had to be `sudo`ed.

Please note that before running pureadmin, you should have a pureftpd fully configured and functional.